# PostgreSQL - Calculate the minimum distance between two points

Tags: postgresql, distance, qgis

I have a fairly substantial point layer (just over 1 million), and I would like to select the shortest distance separating each point from this same layer to another (nearest neighbor). After some research on the internet, I turned to the Cross Join Lateral clause.

However, the request never ends (more than 5 hours without finalization). I compared with the QGis Distance Matrix, **and there the computation time seems to be much faster** (around 10% every 5 minutes). I tell myself that the cause may lie in the poorly formulated request.

Here is the code i used:

```
with couche_points as (select * from public.centroides_batis_all)
select p.id, t.id_2, t.dist
from couche_points p cross join lateral(
select r.id as id_2, p.geom <-> r.geom as dist
from couche_points r
where p.id <> r.id
order by p.geom <-> r.geom
limit 1) as t
```

However, everything looks good to me. Is there a difference in performance between PostGis and QGis?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of the dummy CTE?  All it does is defeat the usage of any index on the real table (which is surely ample explanation for the slowness)

```
select p.id, t.id_2, t.dist
from centroides_batis_all p cross join lateral(
select r.id as id_2, p.geom <-> r.geom as dist
from centroides_batis_all r
where p.id <> r.id
order by p.geom <-> r.geom
limit 1) as t;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you are building matrix like this in your query:

```
   p1  p2  p3  p4  ... pn
p1 --- d21 d31 d41 ... dn1
p2 d12 --- d32 d42 ... dn2
p3 d13 d23 --- d43 ... dn3
p4 d14 d24 d34 --- ... dn4
..........................
pn d1n d2n d3n d4n ... ---
```

but actually you need only half of it because left bottom half just duplicates top right half with points swapping:

```
   p1  p2  p3  p4  ... pn
p1 --- d21 d31 d41 ... dn1
p2 --- --- d32 d42 ... dn2
p3 --- --- --- d43 ... dn3
p4 --- --- --- --- ... dn4
..........................
pn --- --- --- --- ... ---
```

```
select t1.id as id, t2.id as id_2, t2.dist
from
  centroides_batis_all as t1 cross join lateral (
    select t2.id, t1.geom <-> t2.geom as dist
    from centroides_batis_all as t2 where t1.id < t2.id -- the main difference here
    order by dist limit 1) as t2;
```

This query will return pairs such as p1-p2 but not p2-p1 (with same distance of course)

To fix this you could just duplicate rows from the previous query with swapped points:

```
with cte as (
  select t1.id as id, t2.id as id_2, t2.dist
  from
    centroides_batis_all as t1 cross join lateral (
      select t2.id, t1.geom <-> t2.geom as dist
      from centroides_batis_all as t2 where t1.id < t2.id
      order by dist limit 1) as t2)
select
  case t.n when 1 then cte.id else cte.id_2 end as id,
  case t.n when 1 then cte.id_2 else cte.id end as id_2,
  cte.dist
from cte, (values(1), (2)) as t(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have got the option to split your points in four areas.

1 Distance Matrix with 1.000.000 Points needs 1.000.000 x 1.000.000 = 1.000.000.000.000  calculations.

4 Distance MAtrix with 250.000 Points needs 250.000 x 250.000 = 250.000.000.0000 calculations.

Thats just 1/4 of calculations. Of Course you have to show how to handle where the spliited areas come together, but it seems to be much quicker.